# How to exclude the time field from Sumo Logic results?

Tags: sumologic

How do I exclude the Time (_messagetime) metadata field from my result set?
I've tried:

```
field -_messagetime
```

But it gives me the error

```
Field _messagetime not found, please check the spelling and try again.
```

Using:

```
fields -time
```

does not remove the field either.

Currently I'm getting around this by using an aggregate (count) that has no effect on the data.

[EDIT]
Here's an example query:
[image]

Removing the Message (_raw) works.  But removing the time (_messagetime) doesn't.

These results are used as email alerts, so removing the Time field from the Display isn't really an option.

Comment: Hint that Message  is actually _raw, was useful

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer.  I'm trying to export the data as csv, and it keeps adding these hidden fields. You seem to have tried everything I've tried.  Struggling with "_messagetime" and "_messagetimems"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to just turn off the field in the field browser window on the left-hand side of the results:

[image: click the Time field checkbox to get rid of it]

The other option is to aggregate and then remove the aggregate field - even if you just aggregate on _raw (which is the raw message):

```
_sourceCategory=blah
| count by _raw
| fields -_count
```

If you're still having trouble, can you share the rest of your query?

---

Edit based on your new query:

```
*
| parse "Description=\"*\"" as Description
| parse "Date=\"*\"" as Date
| count by Description, Date, Action
| fields -_count
```

Comment: Added an example query

Answer (score 0):

The Time field is there as a result of the timeslice operation as far as I'm aware. The following should do the trick
`| fields - _timeslice`

Comment: It gives me "Field _timeslice not found, please check the spelling and try again."  The results indicate that the Time column is based on the "_messagetime" value.

Comment: what does your query look like?

Comment: Added an example